# SignalR 2.2.2 Asp.Net 4.5 Web Application - Don't have access to the response object in Hub class

Tags: asp.net, signalr, httpresponse

I'm using SignalR 2.2.2 Asp.Net 4.5 Web Application. I want to access the current http response object of the client caller but don't know how. How do I reference the response object? I've tried Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Response but it errors out saying "It does not exist in the current context". Can someone please assist and point me in the right direction.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to access a httpresponse object from within the hub class of SignalR. I've tried getting it from Context object but it seems to be null. Can you help?

Comment: I'm trying to accesI've tried getting it from Context object but it seems to be null. s a httpresponse object from within the hub class of SignalR.  I'm also using select.html2pdf  assembly to convert the current html to pdf. Using the select.htmltopdf library requires access to the response object. Can you help?

Comment: If you are using websockets there is no HttpResponse. Other transports will not give you HttpResponse either since you would break the protocol by writing to it. If the library is writing directly to HTTP Response I don't think SignalR is the right tool for you. If you want to send PDFs over SignalR you will need to be able to save it to a stream (e.g. MemoryStream) and invoke the client with an array created from this stream. (Note that the version of SignalR you are using is using JSON based protocol so sending binary data will be quite inefficient)

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Understood. I'll try as advised by you.

Comment: thanks pavel. your suggestion worked! I first saved it to the memorystream, then converted it to a base-64 digits string on the server side hub class's method. then on the client i converted the string to a blob object and returned the pdf file to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR does not let the user write directly to HttpResponse Stream for a couple of reasons and even if you found a way to do this it is not a good idea:

- when using WebSockets transport SignalR uses webSockets to send messages so writing to HttpResponse would not work (and is not possible)
- SignalR uses its own JSON based protocol if you write anything directly you will most likely create invalid SignalR messages which the client will not be able to process

If you want to send PDFs over SignalR you will need to be able to save it to a stream (e.g. `MemoryStream`) and invoke the client with an array created from this stream. (Note that the version of SignalR you are using is using JSON based protocol so sending binary data will be quite inefficient - it might be better to use SignalR to let the client know there is a PDF they can download and then the client would download it using e.g. HTTP GET request)